# How to init an instance of a Structure with variable as parameter

Tags: variables, parameters, swift

I have a structure:

```
struct Matrix {
let rows: Int, columns: Int
var grid: [Int]
init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
    self.rows = rows
    self.columns = columns
    grid = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: 0)
}
func indexIsValidForRow(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
    return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
}
subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Int {
    get {
        assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
        return grid[(row * columns) + column]
    }
    set {
        assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
        grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
    }
}
}
```

I want now to create an instance in my GameScene with:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


let _numRows: CGFloat = 10
let _numCols: CGFloat = 10


var array = Matrix (rows: Int(_numCols), columns: Int(_numCols))
.....
```

The error:

```
'GameScene.Type' does not have a member named '_numCols'
```

So how can I create in instance of a Matrix using constants as parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields may not depend on each other for initializing. Presumably because the initialization order would be undefined. Move the initialization of array into an init():

```
var array: Matrix

init()
{
    array = Matrix (rows: Int(_numCols), columns: Int(_numCols))
}
```

Comment: explanation: `self` is not available until all class (or struct) properties have been initialized - there's a compiler check on that, so any attempt is reported as a compilation error. Note that in this case, `self` is implicit

Comment: Doing so, I will override the superclass's initialization and initializer GameScene(size:) won't be available:                                 let scene = GameScene(size:skView.bounds.size) - fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(size:)' for class 'Boxes.GameScene'

Comment: In that case you can either consider implementing the initializer overloads that you need and let then call `super.init(...)` or avoid the `init()` and instead move the constants it needs to global lets (e.g. move the lets up just above `class GameScene: SKScene {`).